# Is a minyan required for Sheva Brachot?

Tags: halacha, minyan, sheva-brachos

I am planning to make a Sheva Brachot meal in my home. But, it seems that we have only 7 men. A guest told me that we need a minyan of 10 men. I'm not sure. I know that you can have *zimun* with at least 3. My assumption is that Sheva Brachot is somehow attached to the *zimun* as it immediately follows benching, and there are also some minor changes to the beginning of the *zimun* phrasing, as well.

I'm not asking for psak, here; just for some sources on the matter.

Comment: Please please please don't forget that the goal is to make them happy not to say blessings. If they want a medium size meal that is totally OK. Don't be afraid to ask them and remind them there is no shame in just saying the last blessing. It's actually a good educational opportunity!

Comment: @DoubleAA Ah, yes. Thanks for the reminder. B"N,  I'll mention it.

Comment: DoubleAA +1 but I want to add mazal tov mazal tov

Comment: @DanF I too add congratulations, but do so without invoking astrology.

Comment: @DoubleAA FYI I tried; didn't work. Until you mentioned the source, few people, including me, ever heard of the halacha. I guess, we have to try educating people a bit better.

Comment: @DanF It's not a _problem_ to have a Minyan. It's whatever they want. The goal is to make them happy.

Comment: @DoubleAA I was talking about having 1 person do all 7 brachot. They never heard of it, so we passed the cup.

Comment: @DanF Ah. Sad that the traditional practice has become so neglected so as to be nearly forgotten. Woe unto us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [chabad.org](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/476744/jewish/Newlyweds.htm) the answer is yes because all seven of the brachos (from the wedding) are said - hence the name. Here is the relevant paragraph. Note that if there are other sheva brachot being arranged for this couple, someone who has not been at any of the other meals must be present.

> A minyan (quorum of ten adult Jewish men) must be present in order to
>   recite the Sheva Brachot. This is an important detail to bear in mind
>   when creating the guest list! If there is no minyan, only the last
>   blessing of the Sheva Brachot, the Asher Barah blessing, is recited
>   over a cup of wine -- and this, too, only if there are three adult men
>   (a "mezuman") present.
>
> Another important consideration to take into account when creating a
>   guest list is the need for the presence of a "new face," i.e. someone
>   who wasn't present by the wedding or any of the previous Sheva
>   Brachot. [Click
>   here](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/477370/jewish/Panim-Chadashot-New-Faces.htm)
>   for more on this topic.

Answer (score 8):

The Mishna in Megillah ([23b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=11&daf=23b&format=pdf)) says they need a Minyan, and the Gemara there clarifies that the groom himself can count as one of the 10. The Gemara ([Kallah Rabbati 1:3](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20102&st=&pgnum=103), Ketubbot 7a) derives this requirement from Boaz ([Ruth 4:2](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2904.htm#2)).

Although a Minyan is require to recite the full Sheva Berachot, the Shulchan Arukh ([EH 62:4](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=eh_x7687)) rules that a Minyan is not required to say the blessing "Asher Bara" which is added to all the groom's meals, according to the Shulchan Arukh ([:7](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=eh_x7688)), and to all of his meals that are not just with family ([:7](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=eh_x7688)) that have a Zimmun ([:4](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=eh_x7687)), according to the Rama. The Rama would require a second cup for the one extra Bracha as well ([:9](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=eh_x7688)).

I'll note because you thought to connect the two, that the special Zimmun for a wedding ("SheHaSimcha BiM'ono") is recited at any meal from the time they begin preparing for the wedding until 30 days after the wedding, and also at any meal made specifically to celebrate the marriage within the first year of marriage ([:13](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=eh_x7689)). It is not connected to Sheva Berachot at all. That said, the longstanding custom is to only recite it during the first 7 days of marriage for a first marriage, and during the first 3 days for a second marriage, when the obligation to be happy is especially strong (ibid.).

(Some communities customarily recite a poem before the Zimmun, such as "Nodeh LeShimcha" or "Davay Haser". The Beit Shemuel ([sk 11](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=eh_x7688)) thinks that the latter should be used if all 7 blessings are being recited, but if only the one is being said, then the former poem is to be preferred.)

If you have 7 men at this meal, and you presumably have some guests, then you would say the special Zimmun and the blessing "Asher Bara" afterwards and be thankful for the opportunity to celebrate with the bride and groom in an intimate setting. Enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

Shalom, you asked for sources. There is a full discussion in Chochmas Gershon: Page קסה
https://www.otzar.org/wotzar/book.aspx?168875
ּBlessings! :)

Comment: Thanks for this but we tend to discourage link-only answers. While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. see https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3413/is-a-link-only-answer-to-within-my-acceptable