# Blessing after bread when eating alone

Tags: bentching

When I am eating a meal alone and that meal includes bread what parts of the Birkat Hamazon do I pray? Which parts do I exclude? And please be specific. (I use the Schottenstein Artscroll siddur hachol.)

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! Please note that this site makes no guarantee of validity, and does not offer professional (particularly rabbinic) advice. Treat information from this site like it came from a crowd of your friends, and consult your rabbi for practical guidance. I also recommend our [tour] so you get more of a sense of how the site works.

Comment: ...? all of it except the zimun in the beginning? adjusted, of course, for the additions and substitutions for the day...

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Yairah, and thanks for the question! I hope you'll look around and find other Q&A of interest and stay learning with us.

Comment: Many thanks for the warm welcome msh210and mbloch ... I've actually been peeking over the fence for quite some time now and was thrilled to have a chance to post a question when I couldn't find it in your considerable & facinating archives! Big todah rabah  Isaac Kotlicky, msh210and mbloch  for your time in thoughtfully responding to my question ... particularly since you confirmed what I've been doing!  But a 'friend' contradicted my practice -- pointing to some text he said, "That's the important part right there. The rest that you're saying? You're wasting blessings ...."

Answer (score 1):

The same bentching as when not alone except the invitation part called a "zimun" which is said when there at least males present that are at least bar mitzvah age or older.

Comment: Suppose I was married this past week. Should I recite the _sheva berakhos_?

Comment: @Daniel It's a machloket rishonim.

Comment: @DoubleAA What rishonim say that sheva brachot are said without a minyan?

Comment: @sabba I meant the last one. Most agree that is said even without a minyan, and such is generally accepted halakha

Comment: @DoubleAA OK to clarify, here is the set of full answers http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/67821/is-a-minyan-required-for-sheva-brachot/67823 If there is no minyan, only the last blessing of the Sheva Brachot, the Asher Barah blessing, is recited over a cup of wine -- and this, too, only if there are three adult men (a "mezuman") present.

Comment: @sabbahillel No, that's only true for the Rama. For the ShA it's said at every meal even without a Zimmun. Like I said above it's a machloket rishonim if it's said alone.

Comment: @Daniel this answer doesn't take into account sheva brachos as that wasn't included in the scope of the question.

Comment: @Dude It wasn't excluded from the scope of the question.

Answer (score 1):

You Bentch the same Bentching you'd normally do except without the zimmun (רבותי נברך), and if you are eating in your own house you'd say Harachaman who yivaraych osi. You can probably find this in the Artscroll Siddur, and most Bentchers.

Comment: How do you know this?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I don't know how I could be any clearer. I don't know who you are. You could be a Christian missionary for all I know. If you post an answer I have no reason to trust you know what you are talking about. You should always include how you know something (a verifiable source reference is best, like a location in Shulchan Arukh or a Pasuk) as well as explaining any logic you used in arriving at your answer. Without such support, your claims aren't very valuable to the community.

Comment: I apologize. I'm new here. I didn't really know this works. Thank you for telling me. I'll try to find my source. And in the future I'll try to find my sources. Also, I'm not a Christian Missionary, lol.

Comment: No problem, and welcome aboard. You might find [this](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3887/759) to be a helpful introduction. Also consider checking out the SE [tour].

Answer (score 1):

You would the normal Bircas HaMazon, minus the Zimmun (Invitation; Rabosai Mir Velen Bentshen or Rabosai Nevarech). If you ate something that was not bread, but made of grain, such as a small cake, recite the three faceted blessing.

Comment: I'm fantastically curious: What is this "Blessing after a Snack" with its route for bread? Are there really people who don't bentch after eating bread? (Is this the "one piece of pizza" thing?)

Comment: @SAH - I have seen it somewhere in another siddur, but I cannot find what I'm looking for. I have edited my answer to include the 3 faceted blessing for small cakes, but that wasn't what I was talking about in my other post. :( Sorry; if I find it I'll post it here. :)

Comment: Thanks! I'd not be surprised if there are some people who say something other than Birkat Hamazon--perhaps Al Hamichya?--after a small amount of HaMotzi. I've just never been fully aware of the details.